# is there a way to set a variable to something at the end of foreach loop if condition not met in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

```
foreach (Objecta a in aList())
{
    foreach (Objectb b in bList)
    {
        if (a.variable != b.variable1 && a.variable() != b.variable2)
        {
            a.setVariable("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is that it goes through the foreach loop the first time and it sets variable to error without checking if other values (when it goes through the loop again) finds a match.

What I would like is to wait until it goes through all the lists and at the last `foreach` loop iteration if nothing in `aList` matches the variable target && variable source in `bList` then finally set it to Error flag.

Any suggestions to get around this will be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be useful to show relevant (but small) example input, and explain the desired result. The description is confusing to me.

Comment: foreach (Store s in processFlowStores.getStoresList())
      {

          foreach (Link l in processFlowLinks)
          {

              if (s.getNodeId() != l.getLinkSource() && s.getNodeId() != l.getLinkTarget())
              {
                  s.setID("Error: FailedOperation Error - 123.123.121");
              }
          }
      }

Comment: so there are stores with id and links with sourceid and targetid, if a store has a id with no connection to link source or target then set the id of that store to an error state. the problem is that there is a list of links so say link 1 has not met store id its sets it to error however it shouldnt because l2 has a match for a source of target. because it was set before it does not recognise that this is not an error because it got set previously which i dont want it to do.

Comment: e.g. Store(id=store1)
 Link1(source=store2, target=store3)
 Link2(source=store1, target = store11)

Comment: So basically, you want to find "orphaned" Store? In that case, you have to treat this as a graph problem, where the nodes are the Stores, and the vertex is the Link. Then you need to run an algorithm to traverse the graph, and set error state to all disconnected nodes.

Comment: can you please give an example of this using a random example please or  refer me a source where i can find out more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it the other way around. Search for a match instead of searching for non-matches.

```
foreach (Objecta a in aList())
{
    bool foundMatch = false;
    foreach (Objectb b in bList)
    {
        if (a.variable == b.variable1 || a.variable() == b.variable2)
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundMatch) 
    {
        a.setVariable("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Store s in processFlowStores.getStoresList())
{
    if (!processFlowLinks.Any(l => s.getNodeId() == l.getLinkSource() ||
                                   s.getNodeId() == l.getLinkTarget()))
    {
        s.setID("Error: FailedOperation Error - 123.123.121");
    }      
}
```

EDIT: more compact solution using Linq. Basically, if none of the links has it as either source or target, mark it as error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. So if StoreList is the outer loop and LinkList is the inner loop. You want to search all the links to see if there's an ID that matches the store ID. If you find a match, stop searching the links. After the search through the links, set an error on the store if there was no match, then go to the next store.

```
    foreach (Objecta a in aList())
    {
        var foundMatch = false;

        foreach (Objectb b in bList)
        {
            if (a.variable == b.variable1 || a.variable() == b.variable2)
            {
                fondMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!foundMatch) a.setVariable("Error");
    }
```

Comment: With this solution it will not work if it starts with a valid input and then an error occurs because it never gets set to false if the first one in s is true and the others are false ... (store also has a list of stores)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. foundMatch is set to false before you start searching the links. It only gets set to true if a link is found where the source or target equals the store id, and it would stop searching at that point. If it gets through all of the links and didn't find the store id in any of the links then foundMatch will stay false and you will set the error on the store.

Comment: basically say Stores is s1, s2, s3, s4
and links is s1, s3, s4

store s2 should be error but because store s1 matches link s1, then there is nothing to set store s2 false because there is no link s2

Comment: So with your example, the second time through the outer loop a=s2. You set foundMatch=false then start checking the links. The inner loop looks at the 3 links and doesn't find a match. The inner loop finishes and you see that foundMatch is still set to false so you do a.setVariable("Error") which is setting store s2 to an error.

Comment: just fixed it, thanks for your help, it helped a lot, basically i made another if statement and if it failed i set match to false and then i did continue; 

thanks again for your help :)

Comment: For the other three times through the loop (for s1, s3, and s4) you would set foundMatch=false then start searching the links in the inner loop. You would find a link that matches the store and you would set foundMatch=true and exit the loop because you know there's a match. Outside of the inner loop founMatch is true so you don't set an error.

Comment: foreach (Store s in processFlowStores.getStoresList())
      {
          foreach (Link l in processFlowLinks)
          {
              if (s.getNodeId() == l.getLinkSource() || s.getNodeId() == l.getLinkTarget())
              {
                  setFoundMatch(true);
                  break;   }

              else if (s.getNodeId() != l.getLinkSource() && s.getNodeId() != l.getLinkTarget())
              {
                  setFoundMatch(false);
                  continue;
              }
          }

          if (!foundMatch)
          {
              s.setID("Error");
          }     }

Comment: if you are interested in how i did it with your help, i have included the solution above, thanks again for your help pal. :)

Comment: Your code does the same as mine but it's less efficient. Your else if is the exact opposite of the if so you just need an else. You also set foundMatch to false every time the link doesn't match, which isn't needed of you set foundMatch to false before you go into the loop.

Comment: The solution does what you are asking so either you're not correct explaining what you need or you're not codding it correctly.

Comment: yeah sorry for not explaining it well, thanks for the help, the solution works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

First select all the item values from aList and bList and put them in a seperate array:

```
var aVals = aList.Select(x=>x.value1).ToArray();
var bListVals1 = bItems.Select(x=>x.value1).ToArray();
var bListVals2 = bItems.Select(x=>x.value2).ToArray();
var bVals = bListVals1.Concat(bListVals2);
```

Then, get the values both lists have in common:

```
var correctVals = bVals.Intersect(aVals);
```

These are the correct values and so all the other values are wrong:

```
var wrongVals = aVals.Except(correctVals);
```

Now you have the values that are wrong and can act accordingly:

```
wrongAItems = aList.Where(a => wrongVals.Contains(a.value));
foreach(wrongA in wrongAItems){
    wrongA.setVariable("Error");
}
```